# Running tasks in a specific time in airflow

Tags: jenkins, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I have 3 tasks in an airflow dag.

These three tasks have time dependency

Task 1 - 8 am morning

Task - 2 - 10 am morning

Task -3 - 12 am

I'm not finding any doc referring to that. Its telling to set upstream or downstream jobs only. Could anyone helps on this

I'm using Google CLoud Composer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Airflow structure is made so that the `schedule_interval` is set at the DAG level. This means that you can set the time when an entire DAG will start its execution, but you cannot really specify different execution times per *task*.

The solution if you have three separate tasks that are not dependent on each other is to create **three different DAGs**, and schedule them at those three different times.

---

If instead the time dependency of `task_2` and `task_3` is not so important, but you only care that are executed **one after the other** you can, indeed, set dependencies between the tasks so that `task_2` runs always after `task_1` has finished and `task_3` runs always after `task_2` has finished. To set dependencies you can use the really handy syntax (assuming your tasks have been assigned to variables `task_1`, `task_2`, `task_3`):

```
task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3
```

You can refer to [Airflow official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html) for more information.

---

**TL;DR:**
You cannot schedule single tasks to be run at different specific times, as the only time you can set is the overall DAG run one.

Comment: But I have to watch all these jobs whether it success, then trigger another job

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TimeSensor. Add a time sensor as a sub-task that keeps polling whether the time point has passed.  Although it is less elegant, it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Airflow Documentation:
>
> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#bitshift-composition

After Airflow 1.8 you can also use the bitshift composition.

Instead of setting a time for your tasks,  use this approach:

```
op1 = DummyTask(...)
op2 = DummyTask(...)

op1 >> op2 # same as: op1.set_downstream(op2)
```

The assignment above means that Airflow will only execute `op2` after `op1` is successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

We usually write a help function like:

```
def wait_till(hour: int, minute: int, second: int, dag):
    """get a DateTimeSensor runs till hour: minute: second for default timezone

    Parameters
    ----------
    hour : int
        hour in the day
    minute : int
        minute
    second : int
        second
    dag : [type]
        dag
    """
    target_time_str = f'next_execution_date.in_tz("Asia/Shanghai").replace(hour={hour}, minute={minute}, second={second})'
    task_id_str = f"wait_till_{hour:02d}{minute:02d}{second:02d}"
    return DateTimeSensor(
        task_id=task_id_str, target_time="{{ " + target_time_str + " }}", dag=dag, poke_interval=5
    )
```

Then use this as a timer task inside a dag like

```
wait_till(8,0,0) >> your_task
```

We also tried putting the single task in a separate dag and then use external task sensor to model the task dependencies. The problem with this approach for us is that we often need to reschedule the task.  Rescheduling a dag in airflow would lose all of the logs, which is not acceptable for us.